# How to fix "hyper.http20.exceptions.ConnectionError: Encountered error FRAME_SIZE_ERROR 0x6: Frame size incorrect" error in python

Tags: python, python-requests, python-unittest

I have a requirement to send HTTP/2 get and post request to unit test rest api server.
I tried to use request library but it seems that it doesn't support HTTP/2. So I integrated request library along with hyper transport adapter like below:

```
    import requests
    from hyper.contrib import HTTP20Adapter
    s = requests.Session()
    data={
    "param1": 3000,
    "param2": 10,
    "param3": 2,
    "param4": "2200",
    "param5": "800",
    "param6": "2200",
    "param7": "2000",
    "param8": "1700",
    "param9": "1200",
     "param10": 60,
    "param11": "23:00-22:59",
    "param12": 3,
    "param13": True,
    "param14": 85
    }
    s.verify="/path to ca-cert file"
    s.mount('https://', HTTP20Adapter())
    r = s.post('https://localhost:1000/config', data=data)
    print(r.status_code)
    print(r.url)
```

But it is throwing error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 635, in post
        return self.request("POST", url, data=data, json=json, **kwargs)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 587, in request
        resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 701, in send
        r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/hyper/contrib.py", line 118, in send
        resp = conn.get_response()
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/hyper/common/connection.py", line 136, in get_response
        return self._conn.get_response(*args, **kwargs)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/hyper/http20/connection.py", line 305, in get_response
        return HTTP20Response(stream.getheaders(), stream)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/hyper/http20/stream.py", line 240, in getheaders
        self._recv_cb(stream_id=self.stream_id)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/hyper/http20/connection.py", line 787, in _recv_cb
        self._single_read()
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/hyper/http20/connection.py", line 738, in _single_read
        raise ConnectionError(error_string)
    hyper.http20.exceptions.ConnectionError: Encountered error FRAME_SIZE_ERROR 0x6: Frame size incorrect
```

How to fix this issue?

I tried to explore to increase frame size which receiver receives and I got following from [this link](https://hyper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced.html#flow-control-window-managers)

> To implement one of these objects, you will want to subclass the
> BaseFlowControlManager class and implement the increase_window_size()
> method. As a simple example, we can implement a very stupid flow
> control manager that always resizes the window in response to incoming
> data like this:
>
> ```
> class StupidFlowControlManager(BaseFlowControlManager):
>     def increase_window_size(self, frame_size):
>         return frame_size
> ```
>
> The class can then be plugged straight into a connection object:
>
> ```
> HTTP20Connection('http2bin.org', window_manager=StupidFlowControlManager)
> ```

But I don't know how to make use of this class in my code.